# Using Font Awesome on Xamarin App shows blank box instead of the icon on UWP

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, cross-platform, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome 5 in my xamarin app. I would like to show an icon in a `RadButton` (Telerik):

```
<telerikInput:RadButton
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
          Text="&#xf029;"
          FontSize="30"
          Style="{StaticResource TelerikButtonStyle}"
          Command="{Binding MyCommand}">

          <telerikInput:RadButton.FontFamily>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
              <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" />
              <On Platform="Windows" Value="Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" />
            </OnPlatform>
            </telerikInput:RadButton.FontFamily>

        </telerikInput:RadButton>`
```

For Android, this works fine, but in UWP it shows a blank box.

Answer (score 1):

On Platform should be using "UWP" instead of the ""Windows""

```
<On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" />
```

Comment: Is UWP font is assigned a build action of `Content`?

Comment: Explain more Please.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#windows

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome does not contain `Solid` in the Font Name. Try removing `Solid` from the name as below:

```
<On Platform="Windows" Value="Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4 or greater than replace `Windows` with `UWP` as below:

```
<On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in blank solution and got it working as follows:

1. Added the font in the `Assets/Fonts` folder in UWP project and made sure it has the correct name (in my case I renamed the font to `FontAwesome5.otf`) and Build Action of **Content**:

[image]

2. Used the following to reference the font (note - this sample only sets UWP path, so you should add the other platforms as in your question):

XAML:

```
<Label Text="&#xf11a;" 
   FontSize="40"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome5.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

The proper # suffix can be found out using some font viewer apps, like [dp4 Font Viewer](https://us.fontviewer.de/):

[image: DP4]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Martin, but  tried all this solutios. The file is in Assets/Fonts and i'm sure that the file name is correct. I tried also the UWP and Windows but i have the same result...

Comment: Could you create a quick repro on GitHub or post a simple sample somewhere as a zip? I will look at it and let you know